# rewriterule mixed regular query and clean URL?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to get a regular query appended to any clean URL to be parsed properly. I've spent the last 3 hours trying to attempt this to no avail.

```
/aa/bb/?f=ff
/aa/bb/cc/dd/ee/?f=ff&g=gg
```

should become

```
a=aa&b=bb&f=ff
a=aa&b=bb&c=cc&d=dd&e=ee&f=ff&g=gg
```

instead I get

```
a=aa&b=bb
a=aa&b=bb&c=cc&d=dd&e=ee
```

This is my htaccess line:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/?([a-z0-9]+)?/?([a-z0-9]+)?/?([a-z]+)?/?\??(.*)?$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3&d=$4&e=$5&$6 [NC,L]
```

If you are wondering why I want to do this, it is to accommodate some libraries which do not support clean URLs very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`QSA`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) flag, eg

```
RewriteRule ^...$ foo.php [NC,L,QSA]
```